# What is the purpose of the spacesuit in the crew dragon?

Tags: spacex, spacesuits

[image]

In this picture, in the background, there is a spacex spacesuit. I could not find why they had it. Are they going to use it for a spacewalk? Are they going to test it in microgravity?

So my question is, why did they send that spacesuit to the ISS, what are they going to so with it?

Comment: It's a pressure suit on a test dummy that gathers telemetry on the stresses and environment during the journey.  Astro/Cosmo/Taiko-nauts usually wear pressure suits during ascent and descent after the Souyz 11 accident - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an [article on Space.com](https://www.space.com/spacex-crew-dragon-dummy-called-ripley.html),

> The dummy is part of a full suite of sensors aboard the uncrewed mission, which will produce data that SpaceX and NASA will rely on for future, crewed missions. "We instrumented the crap out of this vehicle; it's got data, sensors everywhere," Kathy Lueders, manager for NASA's Commercial Crew Program, said during the news conference. "Actually having a re-entry, with Ripley in the seat, in the position, is critical."
>
> The sensors inside the Ripley dummy will measure forces and acceleration experienced by a future human passenger, as well as the environment around them.

Yes, they named the mannequin "[Ripley](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/characters/nm0000244?ref_=tt_cl_t2)"